# A question on the size of the topology with respect to the sequential convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

> Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be two topologies on a non-empty set $X.$ Let the sequential convergence with respect to one of the topologies be equivalent to the sequential convergence with respect to the other. Can we conclude that $\tau_1 = \tau_2\ $?

I don't think that it is correct. Our instructor hinted that we can construct a counter-example in the space $\ell^1(\mathbb N),$ the space of all summable sequences of complex numbers. But I can't figure it out. Could anyone give me some hint?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: In $\ell^1$ the weak and norm topology are distinct but have the same convergent sequences. This is known as the Schur property

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti$:$ How to show that in the space $\ell^1 (\mathbb N)$ weak convergence implies norm convergence? Also how to produce an open subset which is in the norm topology but not in the weak topology?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy example. For $\tau_1$ take the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. For $\tau_2$ let every point be isolated, except $0$ whose neighbourhoods will be the co-countable sets.
In both topologies the convergent sequences are those that are constant eventually.

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler examples that do not require functional analysis at all.

The cocountable topology on an uncountable set has this property that a sequence is convergent if and only if it is eventually constant ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768552/convergent-sequence-in-co-countable-topology-iff-sequence-is-eventually-constant)). The same property applies to the discrete topology which is not only different (in the sense of literal equality) but also not homeomorphic to the cocountable one.

For $\ell^1$ space you are dealing with [the Shur's property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property). To see how $\ell^1$ has it read this: [$\ell^1$ Schur property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540458/ell1-schur-property)

Comment: I want a counter-example in $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ @freakish.

Comment: What is $y_n^{(0)}$ in this answer$:$ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42620/960468

Comment: @RabinKumarChakraborty $\ell^1$ is a space of sequences. And in the answer $y^{(n)}$ refers to a sequence of sequences, i.e. $y^{(n)}\in\ell^1$ while $y^{(n)}_k$ is its $k$-th element.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. But the last part of the proof is still not clear to me. First of all I don't think the inequality at the fag end is correct. I have added a comment there in this regard. Also I have a doubt on the approximation which bounds the first part by $\frac {98} {100} \varepsilon.$ How does that $98$ come into the picture?